# Problem in install ubuntu on asus laptop

Tags: 14.04, drivers, system-installation, asus

I have an ASUS laptop with these specifications.

graphics: Nvidia 950m

And I want to install Ubuntu on it. But the system only goes up in the nomedset mode (whether in live or non-live mode).(Also I test another Debian distribution but my problem didn't fix)

After a while, I think that this system has problems with the Nvidia card and my wireless card.
The endless operating system is also installed and running without any problems.

Now how do you fix this problem?
Or is there a way to use endless drivers in Ubuntu?

Even I installed the graphics driver, but the problem did not fix.

thanks

please help me!!!

**Update :**

Errors :

```
[Firmware Bug] : Tsc-Deadline disabled due to Errata;please update a microcode to version 0x52 (or later)

[Firmware Bug] :ACPI region dosent cover the entire command/response buffer.[mem 0xfed 4000 - 0xfed 40487f flags 0x201]vs fed40080fBO
```

Comment: Can some one help?!!?!?!?!

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: yes!!I find the answer I will write it.

Comment: Waiting for the answer...

Comment: maybe this help you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my question.

1. At the first I loged in as nomodeset and use this command

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
   ```

   for solving this

   ```
   [Firmware Bug] : Tsc-Deadline disabled due to Errata;please update a microcode to version 0x52 (or later)
   ```
2. after that I used this command

   ```
   apt-get install nvidia-XXX
   ```

   for solving this

   ```
   [Firmware Bug] :ACPI region dosent cover the entire command/response buffer.[mem 0xfed 4000 - 0xfed 40487f flags 0x201]vs fed40080fBO
   ```

   and then restart my Computer

   Notice :**XXX** must change with the latest nvidia driver version (You can use terminal suggestion using tab key)
3. Finally switch graphics card to intel by launching NVIDIA X Server Settings and select intel graphic card.

[image]

**Notice: On my computer, I can not launch Ubuntu after turning the computer off, but you must first log in to Windows and then restart. Maybe you'll have this problem as well.**

Comment: Can this help you!?

Comment: I have done all this, but still get thé "acpi région.." error. In thé GRUB i have added acpi_osi=Linux pci=msi nouveau.modeset=0 , but i don't know why it is required. Especially the nouveau line, when i use NVIDIA.

Comment: Are you doing step 3?if yes try this maybe your problem solved.

https://superuser.com/questions/464234/can-i-disable-the-external-graphics-card-without-taking-it-off-the-motherboard